# Where are the APIs for the Windows wizard framework?

Tags: .net, winapi, wizard

I'm interested in writing a brute force platform invoke implementation of the Windows wizard framework for .NET.  Where can I find definitions of the Windows APIs involved in this?

Comment: @Hans: I assume he is talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support is part of the [property sheet API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486002%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).